# C# Syntax for Action Delegate

Tags: c#

I'm coming from VB.NET. Now I don't get the right syntax in C#.
I use RelayCommand in WPF with this definition:
`public RelayCommand(Action<object> executeMethod)`

In my ViewModel-class I try this:

```
    public RelayCommand ApplyCommand { get; } = new RelayCommand(o => Apply());

    protected virtual void Apply() 
    {
        // apply something
    }
```

I get the Compiler Error CS0236: "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'name'." ('name' is Apply in the constructor of RelayCommand)
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the words: "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'name'." It requires from you instead of this:

```
public RelayCommand ApplyCommand { get; } = new RelayCommand(o => Apply());
```

do this:

```
static public RelayCommand ApplyCommand { get; } = new RelayCommand(o => Apply());
```

or this:

```
public RelayCommand ApplyCommand { get; init; }
...
// in constructor
ApplyCommand = new RelayCommand(o => Apply());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the static initialiser version, you should initialise during your constructor:

```
class MyClass
{
   public RelayCommand ApplyCommand { get; }

   public MyClass()
   {
     ApplyCommand = new RelayCommand(o => Apply());
   }

   protected virtual void Apply() 
   {
       // apply something
   }
}
```